# Log in web application

Tags: java, html, servlets, netbeans

I'm new to Java and Java EE, so please don't hate much.

I want to create an application which consists of a html document with a login form which transfers control to a servlet for the autentication of a user. I will create a database in netbeans following this tutorial - https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/java-db.html .

Everywhere I looked they used the DAO desingn pattern, but no examles with databases. My question is I saw for the purpose of using the database being used an `EntityManager`. I don't get how in the code we connect to the databe and how the `EntityManager` knows which table to handle. For example in this application the table is just one containg the user's e-mail and password, but what happens if I add a second table for movies lets say?

In my head the implementation is something like this:

---

html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Log in</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" >JCinema</a>
</div> 
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="start_page.html">Welcome</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Book a movie</a></li>
        <li><a  href="#">View schedule</a></li>            
        <li><a href="signup.html">Sign up</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="login.html">Log in</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>    
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">             
  <form class="form-signin" method="post" role="form" action="LoginServlet">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please log in</h2>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
  </form>         
</div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

The User class:

```
@Entity // not sure about this and @Table and @Id, but this is what they used 
       //in this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbrm.html  
@Table ( name = "name_of_table_in_database")
public class User{
  @Id // primary key for tha table
  private String username;
  private String password;
  // setters and getters 
}
```

---

Now for the DAO implementation I think I should have a class containg an entity manager which does the work with the database and inject an instance of it into the servlet form which in it's Post method I will check if the user is valid.

The problem is I don't know how to specify the entity manager to work with the table. I saw something about the persistance.xml file, but have no idea what to do there.

So if someone could explain and show  ( particulary the DAO and entity manager part) how to do such an application that would be greta :). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont advice you to use the tools initially to write you web applications in java, yes I agree Netbeans make the life easy but you have to understand who you pages, Daos, DTOs, and servlets work work with each others so I advice you use eclipse to create three or four simple web sites using servlet jsps and hibernate until you master it then move to auto generated tools such as netbeans. this link might be help you in doing so https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CrxTOcQJqfw
https://javahelpworld.wordpress.com/2014/04/11/simple-crud-using-jsp-servlet-and-mysql/ hopefully this will help you alot to understand most of what you need to build great enterprise solution in java.